# Open more than 1 file using with - python

Tags: python, file-io, with-statement

Normally, we would use this to read/write a file:

```
with open(infile,'r') as fin:
  pass
with open(outfile,'w') as fout:
  pass
```

And to do read one file and output to another, can i do it with just one `with`?

I've been doing it as such:

```
with open(outfile,'w') as fout:
  with open(infile,'r') as fin:
    fout.write(fin.read())
```

Is there something like the following, (the follow code dont work though):

```
with open(infile,'r'), open(outfile,'w') as fin, fout:
  fout.write(fin.read())
```

is there any benefit to using one `with` and not multiple `with`? is there some PEP where it discusses this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
with open(infile,'r') as fin, open(outfile,'w') as fout:
   fout.write(fin.read())
```

It used to be necessary to use (the now deprecated) [contextlib.nested](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested), but as of Python2.7, [`with` supports multiple context managers](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Comment: is there any benefit to using one `with` and not multiple `with`? is there some PEP where it discusses this?

Comment: @alvas No real benefit I think, except it satisfies the "flat is better than nested" principle from "Zen of Python" (`import this`)

Comment: @alvas: It saves you one level of indentation, which is helpful when trying to abide by the 80 characters-per-line (PEP8) limit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing your own class and use it with `with` syntax

```
class open_2(object):
    def __init__(self, file_1, file_2):
        self.fp1 = None
        self.fp2 = None
        self.file_1 = file_1
        self.file_2 = file_2

    def __enter__(self):
        self.fp1 = open(self.file_1[0], self.file_1[1])
        self.fp2 = open(self.file_2[0], self.file_2[1])
        return self.fp1, self.fp2

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.fp1.close()
        self.fp2.close()

with open_2(('a.txt', 'w'), ('b.txt', 'w')) as fp:
    file1, file2 = fp

    file1.write('aaaa')
    file2.write('bbb')
```